# Creating circular menu in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]Iam creating circular menu with html and css.
Basically I want to Achieve Like this
I have used the demo  present in codepen.
Now Basically it contains one level menu with 5 images .
i want to create one more level over that level.
What should i edit in this codepen demo to achieve this?

The html and css code is below.
Please help me to achieve this thing.

```css
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
body{background:#E3DFD2;box-shadow: inset 0 0 20vmin 0 #585247;}
.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:80vmin; height:80vmin;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:inherit;
  transform:scale(0.2) translatez(0px);
  opacity:0;
  transition:transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}
a{
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
  width:47.5%; height:47.5%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform:scale(.5) translateZ(0px);
  background:#585247;
}
a div{
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  opacity:.5;
  transition:opacity .5s;
  border-radius:inherit;
}
p{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0; padding:0;
  font-size:8vmin;
  color:#E3DFD2;
  text-decoration:none;  
}
a:nth-child(1){
  border-radius:40vmin 0 0 0;
  transform-origin: 110% 110%;
  transition:transform .4s .15s;
}
a:nth-child(1) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(1) p{
  left:30%;
  top:30%;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
a:nth-child(2){
  border-radius:0 40vmin 0 0;
  left:52.5%;
  transform-origin: -10% 110%;
  transition:transform .4s .2s;
}
a:nth-child(2) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(2) p{
  right:30%;
  top:30%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
a:nth-child(3){
  border-radius:0 0 0 40vmin;
  top:52.5%;
  transform-origin: 110% -10%;
  transition:transform .4s .25s;
}
a:nth-child(3) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(3) p{
  left:30%;
  bottom:30%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
a:nth-child(4){
  border-radius:0 0 40vmin 0;
  top:52.5%; left:52.5%;
  transform-origin: -10% -10%;
  transition:transform .4s .3s;
}
a:nth-child(4) div{
  background-image: url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(4) p{
  right:30%;
  bottom:30%;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
a:nth-child(5){
  width:55%;height:55%;
  left:22.5%; top:22.5%;
  border-radius:50vmin;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5vmin #E3DFD2;
  transform:scale(1);
}
a:nth-child(5) div{
  background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(5) p{
  left:35%;
  top:35%;
}
span{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:45vmin;
  width:10vmin; height:10vmin;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#585247;
  transform:translateZ(0px);
}
span span{
  position:absolute;
  width:60%;height:3px;
  background:#ACA696;
  left:20%; top:50%;
  border-radius:0;
}
span span:after, span span:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:-1.5vmin;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:inherit;
}
span span:after{
  top:1.5vmin;
}
span:hover + .wrap, .wrap:hover{
  transform:scale(.8) translateZ(0px);
  opacity:1;
}
span:hover + .wrap a, .wrap:hover a{
  transform:scale(1) translatez(0px);
}
a:hover div{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translatez(0px);
}
```

```html
<span><span></span></span>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#"><div><p>text</p></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div><p>text</p></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div><p>text</p></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div><p>text</p></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div><p>text</p></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean you take it from here:https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ZYmZoV

Comment: Yes. You are right. I couldn't be able to post the link. So i directly pasted code.

Comment: @לבנימלכה OP already said it came from a code pen, and he has linked a working example, so I don't get you point.

Comment: As you can see it has one big circle in the middle and four image around it.

Comment: I want to and another four image layer above already existing four image layer.  Now it becomes single circle in middle, four image around it creates first layer, another four image around that makes it third layer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How the new level should look? Just another circle around the it? Can you draw it for us?

Comment: Another four image after already existing four image.  first layer is Single image, second layer is four image, third layer should be again four images

Comment: Can Any one help me with this?